# Atomically write colored text to console in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, console, console-application

I need to print to console some output with color content. Is it possible to do in windows atomically? In Linux there is ansi colors support and it is really very convenient to do complex colored sentences. What about windows? I can do the following:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
printf(" this is how it starts ");
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 10);
printf("YES, it should be green ");
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 0);
printf("back to standard color\n");
```

It seems to me that in asynchronous app this 3 printf will not print text at the same line in console. Here comes 2 solutions in my mind:

1) Use mutex for syncing all console output so as all messages appear sequentially. Seems an overkill  solution for such problem.

2) Use some method to stop console output for a while, print colored line and then start output again.

So, my concern is getting colored line without breaks made by other asynchronous output. Is it possible in windows and what is the best approach?

Comment: Is it Win10 or better?  See [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: @jwdonahue need to have compatibility at least with window 7

Comment: You should add `\n` to the end of the text or flush the output before changing attributes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what if some new text appear(from printf in different thread)  in between changing attributes?

Comment: Low-level [`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) writes an array of `CHAR_INFO` records, which includes the character attributes. You can get the cursor position via `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` and set it via `SetConsoleCursorPosition`, but this makes it non-atomic. You'll have to use a lock if you have multiple threads writing to the console simultaneously.

Comment: You should create an output function that can block or support multi-threading.  Same issue of multiple threads or tasks writing to the same output file.  In Operating System theory its called "resource sharing".  One issue you may have is higher priority threads or tasks calling the same function.  This produces mixed output (output from the lower priority task, then output from higher priority, then remaining output from lower priority).

Comment: Is this C or C++? They aren't the same language. Please pick one.

Comment: @jwdonahue C++, but I can use C in my code

Answer (score 0):

As @eryksun said, use WriteConsoleOutput instead of printf/std::cout.

This is the same as any graphical application.  Only one thread does all the writing.  It has a queue which contains a list of strings and attributes.  When a thread wishes to print something, it pushes the string and the relevant attribute into the queue.  Before printing the writing thread sets the attribute and then prints the string.

You will need to implement your own thread-safe queue.  Mine are normally low volume outputs so I use an array of 256 with a uint8_t counter and atomic markers.  There is no boundary checking: uint8_t wraps back to 0 after 255.  Circular queues work quite well.

You can create a very simple class to do the writing.   I normally use something like this.  Scribbler is the class that does the writing to the screen

```
class COut : public std::ostringstream
{
   Scribbler* writer;
   WORD attr;
public:
   COut(WORD in_attr)
   {
      attr = in_attr;
      writer = Scribbler::Me();
   }
   COut& operator << (std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&))
   {
      if (f == std::endl)
      {
         *this << "\n";
         writer->Push(attr, str());
         str("");
      }
      else
      {
         *this << f;
      }
      return *this;
   }

   template <typename TT>
   inline COut& operator << (const TT& t)
   {
      (*(std::ostringstream*) this) << t;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

This can be used like std::cout and it will do everything you can do with std::cout.   Alternatively, you can write a variant of printf but it isn't that simple when you get into the depths of passing std::arg all over the place.

The thread wanting yellow output would do something like

```
COut yout(FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
...
yout << "Yellow, yellow dirty fellow" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << 25 << std::endl;
```

The thread wanting magenta output would do

```
COut mout(FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
...
mout << ... << std::endl;
```

Nothing gets printed until a std::endl is issued.  You can get quite creative with this with different threads writing to different scrollable parts of the screen using SetConsoleWindowInfo.  It will work as long as there is only one thread that does the writing.  All the other threads just tell it where to write the output and its colour attributes.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I thought about separate thread doing all output.  Looks like this is the only option.